# Terraform-RDS Aurora-VPC - different VPCs error

Tags: amazon-web-services, terraform

I’m trying to create an AWS RDS Aurora with Terraform and other EC2 instances. The EC2 instances are being directed to the VPC with no issues but the RDS can’t join the VPC due to The DB instance and EC2 security group are in different VPCs .

What am I missing here?

I have created the following:

```
variable "vpc_cidr" {
  description = "CIDR for the VPC"
  default = "10.0.0.0/16"
}

resource "aws_vpc" "vpc" {
  cidr_block = "${var.vpc_cidr}"
  tags = {
    Name = "${var.env}_vpc"
  }
}

resource "aws_subnet" "vpc_subnet" {
  vpc_id = "${aws_vpc.vpc.id}"
  cidr_block = "${var.vpc_cidr}"
  availability_zone = "eu-west-1a"

  tags = {
    Name = "${var.env}_vpc"
  }
}

resource "aws_db_subnet_group" "subnet_group" {
  name        = "${var.env}-subnet-group"
  subnet_ids  = ["${aws_subnet.vpc_subnet.id}"]
}

resource "aws_security_group" "RDS_DB_SG" {
    name = "${var.env}-rds-sg"
    vpc_id = "${aws_vpc.vpc.id}"
    ingress {
        from_port = 3396
        to_port = 3396
        protocol = "tcp"
        security_groups = ["${aws_security_group.BE_SG.id}"]
    }
}

resource "aws_security_group" "BE_SG" {
    name = "${var.env}_BE_SG"
    vpc_id = "${aws_vpc.vpc.id}"

    ingress {
        from_port = 80
        to_port = 80
        protocol = "tcp"
        cidr_blocks = ["0.0.0.0/0"]
    }
}

resource "aws_rds_cluster" "rds-cluster" {
    cluster_identifier = "${var.env}-cluster"
    database_name = "${var.env}-rds"
    master_username = "${var.env}"
    master_password = "PASSWORD"
    backup_retention_period = 5
    vpc_security_group_ids = ["${aws_security_group.RDS_DB_SG.id}"]
}

resource "aws_rds_cluster_instance" "rds-instance" {
    count = 1
    cluster_identifier = "${aws_rds_cluster.rds-cluster.id}"
    instance_class = "db.r4.large"
    engine_version = "5.7.12"
    engine = "aurora-mysql"
    preferred_backup_window = "04:00-22:00"
}
```

Comment: Please add the error message you get from `terraform plan`. Also I would recommend to use smaller subnets for the db subnet. With the current setup it would not be possible to add a second subnet in a different AZ.

Comment: @HenrikPingel The error is: ` InvalidParameterCombination: The DB instance and EC2 security group are in different VPCs. The DB instance is in XXXX and the EC2 security group is in XXXX`. I want the EC2 instances and the RDS to be in the same VPC so they will be in the same VPC and subnet.

Comment: You need to split the CIDR for the VPC into at least two subnets. Right now you are using the `vpc_cidr` variable for the VPC and the subnet used for the DB. With that setup you don't have free CIDR ranges in the VPC to create a subnet for ec2 instances in the VPC. Beside that the error seems strange to me as the SG and DB seem to be in the same VPC.